# Hibernate Exception lack of info : Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions

Tags: java, hibernate, session, collections, save

I have a very critical case to handle with this error. I can't share code because it's big and very complicated. The only thing I can share is the exception stack trace and part of the model entity concerned by the exception.
Here is the exception stack trace:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions
at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.setCurrentSession(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:410)
at org.hibernate.event.def.OnUpdateVisitor.processCollection(OnUpdateVisitor.java:43)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractVisitor.processValue(AbstractVisitor.java:101)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractVisitor.processValue(AbstractVisitor.java:61)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractVisitor.processEntityPropertyValues(AbstractVisitor.java:55)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractVisitor.process(AbstractVisitor.java:123)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:293)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:223)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultUpdateEventListener.java:33)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:70)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireUpdate(SessionImpl.java:564)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.update(SessionImpl.java:552)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.update(SessionImpl.java:544)
at com.riskanalysis.server.dao.impl.base.DBDaoImpl.updateObject(DBDaoImpl.java:138)
at com.riskanalysis.server.business.impl.base.DBManagerImpl.saveObject(DBManagerImpl.java:96)
at com.riskanalysis.rttool.web.controller.action.control.ControlsAction.specificSave(ControlsAction.java:295)
at com.riskanalysis.web.controller.action.base.BaseAction.save(BaseAction.java:266)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:269)
at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:170)
at com.riskanalysis.web.controller.action.base.BaseAction.execute(BaseAction.java:154)
at org.springframework.web.struts.DelegatingActionProxy.execute(DelegatingActionProxy.java:110)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:425)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:228)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
at com.riskanalysis.web.controller.BaseActionServlet.doPost(BaseActionServlet.java:156)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:96)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

And here is part of the code concerned by the exception. I say part because the exception concerns saving a collection, and the entity model being saved has 3 collections, while the exception does not indicate which collection is concerned by the exception.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "act_control")
public class Control extends BaseModel implements java.io.Serializable {
  private Long controlId;
  ...

  private Set<ControlResult> controlResults = new HashSet<ControlResult>();
  
  private Set<ControlCommunication> controlCommunications = new HashSet<ControlCommunication>();
  
  private Set<ControlAttachment> attachments =new HashSet<ControlAttachment>(0);
...

@OneToMany(mappedBy="control",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  public Set<ControlResult> getControlResults() {
    return controlResults;
  }

  public void setControlResults(Set<ControlResult> controlResults) {
    this.controlResults = controlResults;
  }
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="control",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  public Set<ControlCommunication> getControlCommunications() {
    return controlCommunications;
  }

  public void setControlCommunications(Set<ControlCommunication> controlCommunications) {
    this.controlCommunications = controlCommunications;
  }
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "control")
  public Set<ControlAttachment> getAttachments() {
    return attachments;
  }

  public void setAttachments(Set<ControlAttachment> attachments) {
    this.attachments = attachments;
  }
```

After analyzing this issue with the dev team and especially with the product architect, he noticed that the exception should show the name of the concerned object/collection, saying that this kind of exception happened before in another project and was showing the exact name of the object causing the issue. So he suggested that this lack of details might be related to java version (project built using JAVA 6) or missing config in hibernate (hibernate 3).

More over this exception is not systematic, and it's not yet clear why and when it happens, still it happened before and might happen to the client which is something we wouldn't wish for :/

So if anyone has and idea about how to get more info in the exception about the name of concerned object or collection, that would be very helpful to us.

Thanks and best regards,

Answer (score 0):

The exception says it already. You are sharing entities and collections between two Hibernate sessions which is not supported. You will have to close the first session before being able to update the entity/collection with the second session. Another way to handle this is to detach the entity/collection from the first session.

Sessions are cheap, so usually they should only span for a transaction. I don't know your setup, but I guess you are sharing a session for the whole request. In one service you then create another session and try to save data with the session of the service that was previously loaded by the session that spans the whole request.